# 変数宣言の後に[[maybe_unused]]属性を置くことは許されるのか

Tags: c++

[[[maybe_unused]]属性](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp17/maybe_unused.html)の説明では、

> 変数宣言では、先頭に[[maybe_unused]]属性を指定する。これは、型、CV修飾、記憶域指定よりも前である。

とあります。
しかし、[主要コンパイラーでは変数の後に置いても意図した動作をする](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFctpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BfmV2mA5pNXUEBWGR0XG2tfWNWS1D3cG9xf1cAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuTgoExJisB9gmGgCC1zfBBLssTMEQs/cmAOxWt7v/u0euyY%2B3WABFdmVdl4GF4lOguPsAKxWFEvACeUQA%2BjC4Zh0CYkWDCWDSNDYfCzAdfjcAbsTugQChFk8Dm42cDQezDvSCIyQK5aNTPl9ibcOPNaJwkbw/BwtKRUJx2ZZrPTFstMPszOseKQCJoJfMANYgSQaAB0kiRADYdbF1jauGYbTb1vpOJJZYbFZxeAoQBp9Yb5nBYDBEMyWAk6NFyJQ0NHYzFgM6yjRaARogGIBEfRFgnV0Zw9QXmMR0QB5CLaNoG7i8RNsQSVhi0Yvy3hYCJeYBuMS0AMN0hYF5GcSdkd4M7tABumCHCswqjaXizJd4jwqPtoeAixCLHiwPtOeBYG/mVAMwAUADU8JgAO6VhKMDcyQQiMTsKQf%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%2BC1LV8/yiGIWaQuDTsIpAKKYooOLUGm6JkrYThs4yvOjALouctIPKy6YvQBZKn8RdkMXqoVXQpfqphGvZ5r059TrurXXY%2BoG9LXK74Ae%2BLiapoS6IgrMSvHtmRblv6NbPV4c9HQtP6LptM7rXWL51kkG14gz2z/QeiGZ6EYIBIE%2BnGBu4CYizmQAkBIWJZxcDOliAwWYThYlUC5PggNsyUFBgqKGHZSyFmhjWOs8Mm7NiRm2DsBNMA9j7AOIceocbjmZl2acCkSY%2BmXKudcw4aY7j3AeCsR52H6kYmzHgHMmA3nvE%2BF8b5hwjyFmPP8k8gIgHdD9WW%2Bt5bQWtoqZWAghwAHoGS6OsKRXYpjUKuVMQALRBKY18xAWB4AUCkecyFaIWyYlbWCoc7YQFcF7Z2hRE5lByD7L20TpIJ20ipCoCl1LR0dkk9iqTDIJOMoMIO6SDLxwiYkkyCgNTmRMmnayHVOD2QyiwBQMDdiILOhaVBC4nh%2BXwGXCu81q7PUimvAgH0m7HySilTgdQWD1MaZ5FpbSmBoIILlbpJAh5FU/KoiQ48KoASnjoLRdUGpNSqW1FenAuoEB6hvfqmDXINKafM9pJxD6jOTEFdY58FqkCWkwFalBLIbXvlom0VoHSHVfu/T%2BkgvhnJsndAMZQL4mhAEiVpSJJAfydG6WIn8P4aBtM1dY1TbocD6eFQFZgSWZ3JUaUg9EUjOEkEAA%3D%3D)ようです。
複数の変数を宣言した中の一つのみに属性を適用する場合は、後に置くしかないように思います。

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, unused1 [[maybe_unused]], unused2; // unused2 のみ警告となる
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

変数宣言の後に[[maybe_unused]]属性を置くことはC++の標準規格として妥当なのでしょうか？

---

確認したコンパイラー:

- gcc 12.1: `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -pedantic`
- clang 17.1: `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -pedantic`
- msvc 19: `/std:c++17 /W4 /Za /permissive-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 変数宣言の後に[[maybe_unused]]属性を置くことはC++の標準規格として妥当なのでしょうか？

はい。妥当(well-defined)です。

> 複数の変数を宣言した中の一つのみに属性を適用する場合は、後に置くしかない

指摘される通り、変数個別での属性適用を実現する構文規則です。

---

1個以上の変数を宣言する単純宣言文(simple-declaration)は、冒頭に属性指定シーケンス(attribute-specifier-seq)を指定でき、その適用対象は同宣言文で宣言される全エンティティ（変数）が対象となります。[C++17 [dcl.dcl]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#2)

> A *simple-declaration* or *nodeclspec-function-declaration* of the form
>
> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *init-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> `;`
>
> is divided into three parts. [...] **The *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to each of the entities declared by the *declarators* of the *init-declarator-list*.** [Note: In the declaration for an entity, attributes appertaining to that entity may appear at the start of the declaration and after the declarator-id for that declaration. - end note] [...]

上記init-declarator-listにおいて個別の変数を宣言(declarator)するとき、変数名(declarator-id)に後続する属性指定シーケンス(attribute-specifier-seq)の適用対象は直前のエンティティ（変数）が対象となります。[C++17 [dcl.meaning]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.meaning#1)

> A declarator contains exactly one *declarator-id*; it names the identifier that is declared. [...] **The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following a *declarator-id* appertains to the entity that is declared.**

Answer (score 3):

許されると考えます。

[宣言子の文法](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl#4)において属性を付けられることが示されています。